# Playing gun bros on Android with iPhone friends

Tags: android, facebook, gun-bros

I have Gun Bros on my Android device (Nexus S), and my pal is playing it on the iPhone, I followed the ingame instructions to add a friend to the brotherhood, but it doesn't work :-/

Is it even possible to add friends from other platforms to your brotherhood? If so, how would I go about adding one who's on the iPhone?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I would like to point out the following: [This feature does not actually allow you to play with another person in real-time, but it does earn you both some additional points.](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/gun-bros/walkthrough)

Comment: I know that it doesn't, thanks. How do I take advantage of it though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gun Bros is not cross-platform. Android players can only add another android player but not players from iphone or FB online.

Answer (score 2):

You can't play with your Facebook account in your iPhone device. You must use game center. So you can't play with your friend with an Android device.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure you link your Facebook account within the game.  When you see your other friends who have their Facebook accounts linked as well, you can recruit them in bro-ops page.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your friends to link their Gun Bros account to their Facebook, when your Facebook picks up that they have a linked account they will automatically be in your bros list.